# How can I remove sessions by session id?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'd like to remove sessions of blocked users.
I store session id in user's document .
How can I remove user's session by session id ?

session module :

```
const session = require('express-session');
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = {
    name : 'mySession', 
    secret : process.env.SESSION_SECRETKEY,
    resave : true,
    saveUninitialized : true,
    cookie : {  expires : new Date(Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 6),
         httpOnly : true
         ,signed :true
    },
    store : new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection : mongoose.connection })
}
```

I tried this but ...

```
let user = await User.findById(req.params.id);
let session = await Session.findById(user.sessionId);
session.remove();
```

Comment: Please edit this question with sample docs & required o/p

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by mongoose :

```
const mongoConn = mongoose.connection;
await mongoConn.collection('sessions').deleteOne({ _id: user.sessionId });
```